# Reading property from object in exception

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm trying to read property from error object whilst I catch the exception. Error comes from Celery worker.

Below I show the console with error from Celery:

```
[2019-12-15 16:38:41,442: ERROR/MainProcess] Task api.tasks.sendSms[139dbbbd-df85-4528-a131-973848fb4f80] raised unexpected: AttributeError("'ERR_UNKNOWN' object has no attribute 'Text'")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/share/backend/backendsmsgateapi/api/tasks.py", line 16, in sendSms
    status = smsServiceObject.sendParcicularSms(receiver, template)
  File "/share/backend/backendsmsgateapi/api/smsService.py", line 38, in sendParcicularSms
    state_machine.SendSMS(message)
gammu.ERR_UNKNOWN: {'Text': 'Nieznany błąd.', 'Where': 'SendSMS', 'Code': 27}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/share/backend/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 385, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/share/backend/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 648, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/share/backend/backendsmsgateapi/api/tasks.py", line 20, in sendSms
    message = getattr(error_object, "Text")
AttributeError: 'ERR_UNKNOWN' object has no attribute 'Text'
```

The Part of my code is:

```
@shared_task
def sendSms(template, receiver, duration):
    try: 
        smsServiceObject = smsService()
        status = smsServiceObject.sendParcicularSms(receiver, template)
        time.sleep(duration)
    except:
        error_object = sys.exc_info()[1]
        message = getattr(error_object, "Text")
        data = {
                "success" : False,
                "error_info": message,
                "receiver": receiver
        }
        return data

    data = {
        "success": True,
        "receiver": receiver
        }
    return data
```

As you can see the problem is in line:

```
message = getattr(error_obj, "Text")
```

But why? In console object ERROR_UKNOWN has property 'Text' and value is 'Neznany błąd'. 
Why it dosen't work? I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Post all relevant code and errors here directly as text.

Comment: OK, give me a moment( I took a photos beacuse it's on raspberry pi).

Comment: Ok, I've changed from photos to pasted code from console and IDE.

Comment: How do you know `error_obj` object has ***`Text`*** attribute?

Comment: because of: gammu.ERR_UNKNOWN: {'Text': 'Nieznany błąd.', 'Where': 'SendSMS', 'Code': 27} in console print

Comment: print(sys.exc_info()) has result: 
(<class 'gammu.ERR_UNKNOWN'>, ERR_UNKNOWN({'Text': 'Nieznany błąd.', 'Where': 'SendSMS', 'Code': 27}), <traceback object at 0x740a6cd8>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
        error_object = sys.exc_info()[1]
        message = error_object.args[0]['Text']
        data = {
                "success" : False,
                "error_info": message,
                "receiver": receiver
        }
        return data
```